# Grid view customization based on row index

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-gridview

Need your help in grid view customization based on row index.

For even positioned row no padding/margin and for odd positioned row some padding/margin before starting row.

I had stuck here for creating this type of grid-view as shown in image.

For Row index 0 row padding 0dp

For Row index 1 row padding Xdp e.g. 10dp

and so on...

How to achieve this in custom grid view.(Grid view customization)

[image]

Like this type of Zig-Zag pattern..

Your suggestions are welcome..

Thanks :)

Comment: You can't do that with a normal `GridView`. However, you could use a `ListView` as the grid and then adding the padding will be easy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
If I will go for Listview then it must have two row (2nd with some margin from left) and both simultaneously can able to scroll horizontally. I am still confused how to do this?